# Load HTML/PHP into JQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery tabs attached to a JQuery dialog and want to load a HTML or PHP page into each tab:

```
<div id='analytics_modal'>
   <div class='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li data-type='discipline_categories'><a href='#discipline_categories'>Discipine Categories</a></li>
        <li data-type='learning_event_time'><a href='#learning_event_time'>Learning Event Time</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id='discipline_categories' class='discipline_categories'></div>
    <div id='learning_event_time' class='learning_event_time'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following, but both loads happen on the first tab, not the specified tabs:

```
$('#analytics_btn').click(function() {  

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json/generate_json_discipline_categories.php",
                success: function(data) {
                        }
                    });
                  
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json/generate_json_learning_event_time.php",
                success: function(data) {
                        }
                    });

        $('#analytics_modal').dialog({
              title: 'Analytics',
              width: '800',
              height: '650',
               position: {
                        my: "left top",
                        at: "left+354 top+129",
                        of: "body"
                    },
              dialogClass: 'dialogClass',
              open: function(event, ui) {
                                  
                  var discipline_categories_tab = $(this).find('.discipline_categories');                                                       
                  discipline_categories_tab.load("charts/discipline_categories_chart.php");
                  
                 var learning_event_time_tab = $(this).find('.learning_event_time');                                                        
                 learning_event_time_tab.load("charts/learning_event_time_chart.php");
                        }
                            }).tabs().css({
                    'max-height': '650px'
                        });
});
```

This is also ignored both both pages overlaid in the one tab:

```
    $('#discipline_categories').load("charts/discipline_categories_chart.php"); 
$('#learning_event_time').load("charts/learning_event_time_chart.php");
```

Comment: How have you confirmed that both URLs are being loaded in the first tab? Also, have you tried `console.log(discipline_categories_tab, learning_event_time_tab)` to confirm you have selected the correct elements? Since the elements you want already have IDs, why not `$('#discipline_categories').load(...)` and `$('#learning_event_time').load(...)` to ensure you're selecting those exact elements?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make any difference, both PHP pages (they are charts) display in the one tab, not the specified tabs/divs:      $('#discipline_categories').load("charts/discipline_categories_chart.php");                         $('#learning_event_time').load("charts/learning_event_time_chart.php");

Comment: call your associate ajax call on tab change event, not all in a single button click. Only call 1 ajax which is responsible for singal tab when button click.

Comment: Like?  Can you give an example?

Comment: What HTML is returned by the PHP files? Is it possible they're corrupting your DOM and making it look like everything is ending up in the same `<div>`? Also, if you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be easier for us to debug.

Comment: The php pages are not corrupting.  The method for loading pages just needs to be changed to  tab change event.

Answer (score 0):

This works and the PHP charts load into respective tabs OK.  But the code is not exactly pretty:

```
$('#analytics_btn').click(function() {      
        
        $('#analytics_modal').dialog({
              title: 'Analytics',
              width: '800',
              height: '650',
               position: {
                        my: "left top",
                        at: "left+354 top+129",
                        of: "body"
                    },
              dialogClass: 'dialogClass',
              open: function(event, ui) {
                  
                 discipline_categories_tab = $(this).find('.discipline_categories'); 
                 learning_event_time_tab = $(this).find('.learning_event_time');    
                  
                        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json/generate_json_discipline_categories.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    discipline_categories_tab.load("charts/discipline_categories_chart.php");
                        }
                    });
                  
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "json/generate_json_learning_event_time.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    //learning_event_time_tab.load("charts/learning_event_time_chart.php");
                        }
                    });
                        }
                            }).tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        var active = $(this).tabs('option', 'active');
        if(active == 0){
            //discipline_categories_tab.load("charts/discipline_categories_chart.php");
        } else if(active == 1){
            learning_event_time_tab.load("charts/learning_event_time_chart.php");
        }
        
    },
        }).css({
                    'max-height': '650px'
                        });
});
```